# Deleting elements out of a json file without getting "null"

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `JSON` formatted text file that I'm using as kind of a database.

I read the file, use `JSON.parse` to turn it into an object,  use `delete` on an element, then I `JSON.stringify`the object and write it back to the file.

However the resulting file has "null" in the place where the object used to be, <s>which isn't proper JSON, so my program will crash the next time the file is parsed.</s> I don't like it.

How can I delete elements from my file without getting "null" where the element used to be?

Here's how I do it:

```
data = fs.readFileSync("./manifest/test.json");
contents=JSON.parse(data);

//some logic

delete contents.customers[i].files[j];
fs.writeFileSync("./manifest/test.json",JSON.stringify(contents,null,4));
```

And the resulting file before:

```
    {
    "customers": [
        {
            "customer": "test",
            "files": [
                {
                    "name": "test.flv",
                    "location": "cloudfront.url.com/check.flv"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And after:

```
    {
    "customers": [
        {
            "customer": "test",
            "files": [
                null
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Using `delete` on an _Array_ does not move the keys of other items, but rather just makes it as if the deleted key was not initialized. You can think of it as `a = [0, 1, 2]; delete a[1]; a;` being identical to `a = []; a[0] = 0; a[2] = 2; a;`

Comment: simply set a value to String (the actual function) instead of null because functions are completely deleted from JSON.stringify's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contacts.customers[i].files.splice(j, 1);
```

The result is still valid JSON though.  `JSON.parse` should succeed.  The error may lie elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, I honestly never tried it. I just assumed that it would fail. But I like your solution better